# How to merge multiple images into one image using opencv python

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I am trying to merge images while iterating through a function, the function iterates through the folder get each image, now I am trying to merge all the images while iterating and merge them into one single image.

```
directories = [ x for x in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isdir(x) ]
image_list=[]
images = []

def randomFile(directory):
    files_list = os.listdir(directory)
    random_num = random.choice(files_list)
    print(random_num,directory)
    img_1=cv2.imread((os.path.join(directory,random_num)))
    if img_1 is not None:
        images.append(img_1)
    files_list.remove(random_num)
    img1_g_noise = cv2.merge(images)
    return img1_g_noise

for x in directories[1:]:
    randomFile(x)
    cv2.imshow("img1_g_noise",randomFile(x))
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

I am able to access all the images but not been able to merge into one single image, the list images=[] contains all the pixels of all three images

Comment: What do you mean by "merge into one single image"? What is the expected output (list or NumPy array, what is the shape of the NumPy array)? Are you trying to add all the images to a list? I don't think `cv2.merge` is what you are looking for (read the OpenCV documentation).

Comment: @Rotem, Trying to multiple image into one image

Comment: What do you mean "multiple image into one image"? Getting the average image of all the input images?

Comment: combing multiple images which are inside multiple directories into one single image

Comment: What do you mean by "combing"? How many color channels does the combined image has?

Comment: @Rotem, what I am really trying to do is to make a collage of images , multiple images into one single big image, lets say the channel is rgb

Comment: OK, Don't use `cv2.merge`. How many rows and columns do you expect in the collage? Please edit your post to be more clear. Please make sure your question is not already asked.

Comment: lets say there are 4 images, 2 rows and 2 columns

Comment: What about the resolution? Does all the images have the same resolution? Do we need to resize the images? Please search for it in Google first. In case you don't find an answer, **edit your question** to be more clear (I am not going to post an answer, but maybe someone else does, if the question is more clear).

Answer (score 0):

In Python/OpenCV/Numpy, if all 4 images are the same dimensions, then, if input is img1, img2, img3, img4, the following will make an image that is a 2x2 collage of the input images.

```
img12 = np.hstack((img1, img2))
img34 = np.hstack((img3, img4))
result = np.vstack((img12, img34))
```

If the images are not the same size, then either crop or resize them to the same size.

Answer (score 0):

You can try replacing
img1_g_noise = cv2.merge(images)
with:

```
img1_g_noise = cv2.cvtColor(images[0], cv2.COLOR_RGB2RGBA)
images.pop(0)

for img in images:
    img1_g_noise = cv2.addWeighted(img1_g_noise,0.5,cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2RGBA),0.5,0)
return cv2.cvtColor(img1_g_noise, cv2.COLOR_RGBA2RGB)
```